# How can I put bullets in a magazine

Tags: receiver

I picked up some bullets and I have a half-empty magazine. How can I put the bullets in it?

Comment: I thought this was an actual gun question and was really confused why it was here. Then I read the tag description. didnt think a game like that existed where you have to actually load the clip... neat.

Comment: You should be able to hit `?` and pull up a help menu that gives all the hotkeys available and highlights suggested options.

Comment: @Batophobia this particular information is missing from the help menu, that's why I wrote the answer and self-answered it after finding out.

Comment: You shoot the magazine. Clearly.

Comment: I was confused by the question title as well. I was going to suggest using the `<li>` tag.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To put bullets into a magazine, you first have to holster your weapon. The complete sequence is:

- Put the magazine in your left hand by either taking the current one out of your gun (<kbd>E</kbd>) or selecting one from the inventory (<kbd>0</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd>).
- Press <kbd>~</kbd> to holster your gun.
- Now that you have your right hand free, you can add bullets to the magazine with <kbd>Z</kbd>
- Take your gun out again with <kbd>~</kbd>
- Put the magazine into the gun (<kbd>Z</kbd>) or put it into the inventory (<kbd>0</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd>)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer from Philipp...  Beware that your keyboard must be configured in a way that doesn't treat <kbd>~</kbd> as a dead key.  For instance, my keyboard is Brazilian, so I'd have to hit <kbd>~</kbd>, followed by <kbd>space</kbd>to get a <kbd>~</kbd>, but that doesn't work in the game.

On Linux, I switched to an American keyboard setting with:

```
setxkbmap us
```